# Time trend analyses using “years vs. rate” ecological data?

Tags: time-series, logistic, categorical-data, trend, wald-test

Looking at my time trend plot, I wonder how to test the statistical significance in the trend shown in the plot here given this simple "years vs. rate" ecological data? I tried ANOVA turned in $p<0.05$ treating year variable as categorical. But it's not satisfactory. Also, there is one article I reviewed suggested Wald statistics to test the time trend. But I found nothing in Google about Wald stats for time trend.

[image]

My data (First six obs):

```
head(yrrace) 
  year racecat rate       
1 1995       1 14.2     
2 1995       2  8.7     
3 1996       1 14.1    
4 1996       2  7.5    
5 1997       1 13.3    
6 1997       2  8.3
```